# How to use selector to locate each child in a foreach loop in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery and I want to use selector to locate each child in a foreach loop:

```
   $('div.parents').children('a').each(function(i) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).trigger( "click" );
        },2000 + i * 2000); 
    });
```

However, ***$(this)*** seems not work at all. The list looks like this:
And if I change  ***$(this).trigger( "click" );*** to  ***$('a').trigger( "click" );*** it will open all the links at once.

```
<div class="parents">
<a class="child"></a> 
<a class="child"></a> 
<a class="child"></a> 
...
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `this` inside the setTimeout callback does not point to the clicked element, you can use a closure variable to fix this issue

```
$('div.parents').children('a').each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.trigger( "click" );
    },2000 + i * 2000); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation and fast response. :-)

Answer (score 3):

To let `this` inside `setTimeout` points to `this` outside of `setTimeout`,

you can use jQuery's [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$('div.parents').children('a').each(function(i) {
        setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
            $(this).trigger( "click" );
        },this),2000 + i * 2000); 
    });
```

Or [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) [works only in [browsers compatible with ECMAScript 5](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/)]:

```
$('div.parents').children('a').each(function(i) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).trigger( "click" );
        }.bind(this),2000 + i * 2000); 
    });
```